# Recursive function with already predefined prototype

Tags: java, recursion

I have a function with this already predefined `prototype: int sumInd(char ch, String str)` .
I need to create recursive function which returns sum of indexes where character d is appearing inside String n.

Is it possible with this prototype, if no, how would you do it?

Comment: Did this really called 'prototype'?

Comment: Side note: there are no "prototypes" in the Java language. One part of learning programming is to make sure that you are using the correct terminology. Typically people can't help you if you are using words that do not make sense to others ...

Comment: @Jägermeister I understand there isn't prototypes, but I already have defined functions which I need to build, and I called it prototype. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @NikolasSpark The term you're looking for is [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature).

Answer (score 0):

Without writing the entire solution for you, here are some directions :

The sum of indices containing the given character can be broken to the sum of indices containing that character in the first `str.length - 1` characters of the String plus `0` or `str.length - 1` (the index of the last character), depending on whether or not the last character is equal to the given character.

The trick is to remove the last character of the String before each recursive call, in order for the remaining characters to have the same index they had in the original String.

Comment: It's worth noting that in order to fix [a bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6294060), `String.subString` _copies_ the underlying array into a new array; this makes the recursive approach have horrible performance. Unless you use the `char[]` directly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Good point, but I'm assuming performance is not a requirement in this exercise. Otherwise, recursion wouldn't be used in the first place.

Comment: @Eran Hi Eran, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Eran Hi Eran, Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately, I am having a little trouble with that.
For example, my base is when str.length() == 0.
My return: 
return str.indexOf(d, 0)+ recursiveSum(d, str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
But it's not working.

Comment: Hi @Eran, Sorry for bothering. I just needed to sum indices of lastIndexOf. :) Thanks.

Comment: @NikolasSpark Why use indexOf or lastIndexOf?  You want to check if the last char of the String is d. i.e. `return (str.charAt(str.length()-1)==d?str.length()-1:0) + recursiveSum(d, str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)); `.